# How would I locate all text files on my server that have the current IP address?

Tags: linux, centos8

This is what I have tried so far.

```
ls /bin/ /usr/bin | sort | uniq | grep ip
```

Comment: Files don't have IP addresses so you're going to have to explain what you mean.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
find / -type f -exec grep -l IP {} \;
```

this search for all files from root (`/`) and execute `grep` to get the filename